# how can i fetch a file that i have already upload and i want to delete it and replace it using bootstrap file input

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-file-input

i want to fetch the file based on my `applications_id` and i want to see it in the bootstrap file input and i want to delete it and replace with a new file. how can i do it. below is what i have tried .can anyone help me .i am stuck.

this is my contoller function SoleProprietorController.php

```
    public function uploadImages(Request $request, $applications_id)
    {
       $applications = new Applications;

     //  $KRAPIN = Input::get('KRA_unique_field');
      $applications_id = Input::get('applications_id_unique_field');

    if ($request->hasFile('breg_cert')) {
       if ($request->file('breg_cert')->isValid()) {
                  // request()->breg_cert->move(public_path('breg_cert'), $imgName);
            // $imgName = basename($request->breg_cert->store(public_path('breg_cert')));
           $imgName = basename($request->breg_cert->move(public_path('breg_cert')));
           $applications->breg_cert = $imgName;
       }
      return response()->json(['uploaded' => '/breg_cert/'.$imgName]);
      }

    }
```

this my web.php

```
Route::post('/uploadImages/{applications_id}', 'SoleProprietorController@uploadImages')->name('home');
```

this is my bootstrap file in my blade

```
 <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
 <label for="validationServer023">Upload Business Registration Document</label>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div content="{{ csrf_token() }}" class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier1">
    <input id="file-0a" name="breg_cert" value="" class="file" accept="text" type="file"> <br />

    </div>
 </div>   
</div>

<script>

    $("#file-0a").fileinput({
        initialPreview: [
            "<img src='/images/php' class='file-preview-image'>",
        ],
        showUpload: true,
        showRemove: true,
        showCaption: true,
        showPreview: true,
        showClose: false,
        autoOrientImage: true,
        showUploadedThumbs: false,
        uploadAsync: false,
        uploadUrlThumb: false,
        deleteUrl: "/public/KFS_Business_Registration_Certificates",
        uploadUrl: "/uploadImages/{applications_id}",
        // dataUrl: "/breg_cert/",
       // uploadUrl: '/public/KFS_Business_Registration_Certificates', // you must set a valid URL here else you will get an error
        theme: 'fa',
        uploadExtraData: function() {
            return {
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            };
        },
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'jpeg'],
        overwriteInitial: false,
        maxFileSize: 500,
        maxFilesNum: 10,
        //allowedFileTypes: ['image', 'video', 'flash'],
        slugCallback: function (filename) {
            return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use code like this to store uploaded file and associate it with your Applications

```
if ($request->hasFile('breg_cert')) {
   if ($request->file('breg_cert')->isValid()) {
       $imgName = basename($request->breg_cert->store(public_path('breg_cert')));
       $applications->breg_cert = $imgName;
   }
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#storing-uploaded-files

> To store an uploaded file, you will typically use one of your configured filesystems. The  UploadedFile class has a store method which will move an uploaded file to one of your disks, which may be a location on your local filesystem or even a cloud storage location like Amazon S3.
>
> The store method accepts the path where the file should be stored relative to the filesystem's configured root directory. This path should not contain a file name, **since a unique ID will automatically be generated to serve as the file name**.

2. To handle delete/replace create a corresponding controller method and POST route and then provide the route to deleteUrl option.

In the above method check the filename associated and unlink it. (actual code depends on what `dd($request);` output)

3. To show stored image as preview add option to $("#file-0a").fileinput({

```js
initialPreview: [
    "<img src='/images/path-to.jpg' class='file-preview-image'>",
],
```

Comment: hi Constantine i want to view the file even when i fresh the browser and i want to view it based on applications_id.and also delete it permanently from the breg_cert folder.how can i achieve that.

Comment: the code is not renaming the file neither it is not save the file in the ```breg_cert``` directory.

Comment: Check your config/filesystems.php and make sure configured directory is writeable.

Comment: the path is correct in config/filesystems.php.i just want to show  the saved image in my bootstrap file input.that if i come after two hours and open the system i can see the image i upload .

Comment: where should i add it like this  ````<input id="file-0a" name="breg_cert" value="" class="file" value="{{$applications_id->applications_id}}" accept="text" type="file" initialPreview: [
    "<img src='/images/path-to.jpg' class='file-preview-image'>",
],> <br />````

Comment: what path should indicate here ````initialPreview: [ "<img src='/images/path-to.jpg' class='file-preview-image'>", ],```` because after adding the code its not showing any image.plus this code was not save the image into the path but it is upload.and my path is correct ````if ($request->hasFile('breg_cert')) {
   if ($request->file('breg_cert')->isValid()) {
       $imgName = basename($request->breg_cert->store(public_path('breg_cert')));
       $applications->breg_cert = $imgName;
   }
}````

Comment: and  how can i write a function to handle delete/replace create a corresponding controller method and POST route and then provide the route to deleteUrl option.

Comment: OK, when you load the page you should pass path to image that you would like to show. If you do not have an image yet - do not provide initialPreview option. Please read the docs at http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#initialPreview

Comment: how can i set the path just show me.i want to pass a unique name to be fetching the image.how can i achieve that

Comment: I can't say any more without a code. Show your full code for model and view

Comment: still waiting for your help

Comment: i am still waiting for your answer

Comment: I do not know your paths, model logic, etc. so I can't give you a ready-to-use solution. Here is the quick and dirty solution how to output image to initialPreview https://pastebin.com/mjB9AUuC